# Не могу изменить пароль пользователя в Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возникла проблема. В Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2017
происходит следующее: есть пользователь, у него для входа  есть некий дефолтный пароль, который я не знаю(изображен на первой картинке). Я меняю ему пароль, допустим 123456, сохраняюсь. Захожу снова, а там опять стоит этот дефолтный пароль, будто ничего не поменялось. Такая проблема у меня с любым пользователем, которому я пытаюсь поменять пароль. Кто-нибудь сталкивался подобным? Подключаюсь к локальному серверу,при входе использую аутентификацию с помощью Windows, может проблема в недостатке прав доступа?[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там просто всегда показывается одинаковое количество звездочек, вне зависимости от того, какой реальный пароль выставлен :)

Comment: Проверьте, какой режим аутентификации включен на SQL. Может быть он "Windows authentification only"? При таком режиме дает менять пароль SQL пользователей, но зайти под ними не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что он по дефолту ставит определенное количество знаков в пароле, даже если сам пароль гораздо короче( Всем спасибо, кто ответил.

Answer (score 0):

Запускаем из терминала команду sqlcmd и выполняем следующий скрипт:

```
USE master
GO 
CREATE LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD = N'qwep[]ghjB1'; 
GO 
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'test', @rolename = 'sysadmin'
```

И несколько ссылок для закрепления материала:

[Как сбросить пароль SA в Sql Server](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-SA-%D0%B2-Sql-Server)

[Сменить пароль sa в sql через командную строку](http://pyatilistnik.org/menyaem-parol-sa-v-sql/)

[Изменение пароля sa в MS SQL Server](https://medium.com/@Chtyllhu/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-sa-%D0%B2-ms-sql-server-ec373291bd9a)